# how to change this access code so that radio buttons are removed

Tags: ms-access, forms

please tell me how to change this access code so that radio buttons are removed and on clicking the import button itself the all 4 excel sheets are imported ( in other words code of all 4 radio buttons is excecuted ). I'll be glad if you can  help me out however negative comments are most welcome as well :-)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
On Error Resume Next
If IsNull(Me.txtFileName) Or Len(Me.txtFileName & "") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "please select the excel file"
    Me.cmdSelect.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Select Case Me.FrameSheet
    Case 1
    CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet1"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet1", Me.txtFileName, True, "incoming calls!"
    Case 2
    CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet2"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet2", Me.txtFileName, True, "incoming sms!"
    Case 3
    CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet3"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet3", Me.txtFileName, True, "outgoing calls!"
    Case 4
    CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet4"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet4", Me.txtFileName, True, "outgoing sms!"

    Case Else
    MsgBox "Select which Sheet you want to import"
    Exit Sub


End Select

End Sub

Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()
'    DoCmd.Quit
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSelect_Click()

    Dim strStartDir As String

    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim lngFlags As Long

    ' Lets start the file browse from our current directory

    strStartDir = CurrentDb.Name
    strStartDir = Left(strStartDir, Len(strStartDir) - Len(Dir(strStartDir)))


    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, _
                        "Excel Files (*.xls)", "*.xls")
    Me.txtFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:=strStartDir, _
                     Filter:=strFilter, FilterIndex:=3, Flags:=lngFlags, _
                     DialogTitle:="Select File")


End Sub
```

Comment: You really should add ", dbFailOnError" to all your CurrentDB.Execute statements, since that will insure you don't end up with inconsistent updates because the whole update will fail if any part of it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the actual select statement

something like this

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsNull(Me.txtFileName) Or Len(Me.txtFileName & "") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "please select the excel file"
        Me.cmdSelect.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

        CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet1"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet1", Me.txtFileName, True, "incoming calls!"

        CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet2"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet2", Me.txtFileName, True, "incoming sms!"

        CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet3"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet3", Me.txtFileName, True, "outgoing calls!"

        CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from Sheet4"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet4", Me.txtFileName, True, "outgoing sms!"

    End Sub
```